# Error de Carpeta de Dart en MacOS

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hola tengo este problema que me muestra `$flutter doctor`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo lo demás ya lo tengo bien instalado pero es esto lo que no me permite seguir.

Comment: Saludos Alan, bienvenido a SOes, https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour -> primer punto de visita para que veas la dinámica del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla. Del error que te dice, te hago una pregunta, ¿cómo verificas las variables de entorno, esas que están en el `PATH` ?

Comment: Muchachos, eviten ponerle negativo, recién llega y no ha visto el tour.

Comment: Bienvenido, acostumbra a agregar los textos de error en tu pregunta, ya que no todos los miembros pueden visualizar el texto de la imagen. Te invitamos a revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

solo tienes que desinstalar dart

```
brew uninstall dart
```

luego corres de nuevo

```
flutter doctor -v
```

y ya no te marca error